# How do I express this?

Tags: c++, equation-solving

I'm trying to work out how to write the following:

```
total = (value * 0.95 ^ 0) + (value * 0.95 ^ 1) + (value * 0.95 ^ 2) ...
```

or:

```
x = (y * z ^ 0) + (y * z ^ 1) + (y * z ^ 2) + (y * z ^ 3) ...
```

This expresses how to calculate x for 4 iterations, but how can I express this to work with a variable number of iterations? Obviously I could create a loop and add the values together, but I'd really like to find a single equation that solves this.

I'm using c++ but I guess this isn't really a language specific problem (sorry I literally don't know where else to ask this question!).

Any ideas?

Thanks,
Chris.

Comment: use loop to do this

Comment: what do you mean with "single equation" ? I mean the equation you wrote is also not complete, but has some `...` in the end and if you think about it, the `...` just stands for "repeat the steps for some index where the index goes from some number to some larger number (for sure not infinity)" and thats a loop. Why dont you want to write a loop? A recursive function would be an alternative

Comment: BTW, a tiny bit of calculus enables you to compute the sum of all integral powers of 0.95; this is not C++ but some basic math. Read about [power series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_series). Ask someone who knows a little bit of math (he does not need to be able to program)

Comment: Why don't you want to use a loop? I think it's useless for programming purposes to look for something complicated when a loop is enough. If you're looking for a formula, this is more a mathematical question than a programming question.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. I felt that there could be a more elegant way to express this rather than using a loop (as molbdnilo has shown). @Basile Unfortunately the math guy is sick today!

Comment: The `^` operator in C++ isn't a power operator but an exclusive or operator ([see here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3akey979.aspx)). To do powers in C++, use `std::pow(x, y)` (this function is in `#include <cmath>`).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Equation-wise solving, this is a [geometric series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series) and can therefore be calculated with

```
double geometric_series(double y, double z, int N) {
  return y * (std::pow(z, N) - 1.0) / (z - 1.0);
}
```

but the same result can be obtained with some **fun** C++ metaprogramming: if you know the number of iterations in advanced and you're allowed to use C++17 features and [fold expressions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/fold) you could do as follows

```
template<std::size_t... N> 
double calculate_x(double y, double z, std::index_sequence<N...>) { // [0;N[
 auto f = [](double y_p, double z_p, double exp) {
   return y_p * std::pow(z_p, exp);
 };
 return (f(y, z, N) + ...);
}

template <std::size_t N>
auto calculate_x(double y, double z) {
  return calculate_x(y, z, std::make_index_sequence<N>{}); 
}
```

Alternatively this can also be done with pre-C++17 templates

```
template <int N>
double calculate_x(double y, double z) {
  return calculate_x<N-1>(y, z) + (y * std::pow(z, N - 1));
}

template <>
double calculate_x<0>(double, double) {
  return 0;
}
```

Otherwise a simpler solution would be to just use a loop

```
double calculate_x_simple(double y, double z, int N) {
  double ret = 0.0;
  for (int i = 0 ; i < N ; ++i)
    ret += y * std::pow(z, i);
  return ret;
}
```

Driver for the code above

```
int main() {

   // x = (y * z ^ 0) + (y * z ^ 1) + (y * z ^ 2) + (y * z ^ 3)
   double y = 42.0;
   double z = 44.5;
   std::cout << (calculate_x<3>(y, z) == calculate_x_simple(y, z, 3)); // 1

}
```

Answer (score 9):

There is no need for a loop here, you "just" need to employ some maths.

Note that you can rewrite that as

y * (z<sup>0</sup> + z<sup>1</sup> + ... + z<sup>n</sup>)

Now, the series

z<sup>0</sup> + z<sup>1</sup> + ... + z<sup>n</sup>

sums to

(z<sup>(n+1)</sup> - 1) / (z - 1)

so your equation would be

x = y * (z<sup>(n+1)</sup> - 1) / (z - 1)

Comment: Perfect! I just needed to add y to that to get the result I was after! Thanks a million!

Comment: I am not an expert in math, but shouldn't the exponent be (n+1) instead of just n?
Take a look at wolfram alpha: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+z%5En+n%3D0+to+m

Comment: @AndreasH. Indeed it should. I mistakenly took the sum from 1 to n. (When you're over 10k rep, you start getting upvotes for wrong answers ;-)

Answer (score 3):

If a loop would be the only option:

```
double x = 0;
int n = 5;
for(int exponent = 0; exponent <= n; ++exponent)
  x += y*pow(z, exponent);
```

Answer (score 3):

As you mentioned, it seems reasonable to use a loop. But if you know the amount of iterations at compile time, you could use templates like this:

```
template <int n>
double foo(double y, double z)
{
    return foo<n-1>(y, z) + y * std::pow(z, n);
}

template <>
double foo<-1>(double, double)
{
    return 0;
}
```

With just a little bit of optimisation this will unfold to a **single equation**.

Example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

template <int n>
double foo(double y, double z)
{
    return foo<n-1>(y, z) + y * std::pow(z, n);
}

template <>
double foo<-1>(double, double)
{
    return 0;
}


int main()
{
    std::cout << foo<2>(2,3) << std::endl;
}
```

Output: 26

Comment: Interesting! Thanks for the reply!

Comment: If `n` is large then [http://stackoverflow.com/a/40657531/2378300] is faster. However, if `n` is "small" then the solution above is the fastest.

Answer (score 2):

you can just use `math.pow` function with a for loop

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(void) {
    int i;
    int n = 5;
    double y = 0.5;
    double z = 0.3;
    double answer = 0;
    for (i = 0  ; i < n ; i++)
        answer += y * pow(z,i);

    printf("%f", answer);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `n` as the number of iterations,

```
#include <cmath>
double foo(double y, double z, int n)
{
   double x =0;
   for(int i = 0 ; i<n; ++i){
      x+=y*std::pow(z,i);
   }
   return x;
}
```

Where [`std::pow`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/pow) is the power function.

Answer (score 2):

It can be expressed as a sum from n=0 to m. It can be expressed in a single formula, according to [wolframalpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum%20x*z%5En%20n%3D0%20to%20m).

Comment: Thanks for the link - looks beyond me though! I think I'm going to need to invest some time in math / physics!

Answer (score 2):

Don't know if this fulfills your purpose, but you can use recursion(which in real terms is a loop only :) )

```
int x = evaluate(y, z, count);


int evaluate(y,z, count)
{
   if (count <= 0)
    return 0;

   return (evaluate(y, z, count-1) + y*z^count);
}
```